# path error out of subversion context

Tags: windows-7, svn, delphi

Delph XE5 on Dell 5810 Windows 7 64.
I was just trying to commit some modifications n an old program code.
At my right clicking on program name (Project Manager)to get to subversion, I had following error  message:
"the filename, directory name, or volume label in incorrect: libapr-1.dll"
I have accurately checked all names and paths I could think about, Delphi options etc. No solution found.
Please give some hint

Comment: Probably the Dash Character (`-`) is not eatable by the Graphical User Interface of the `subversion` Static Software Application. We would go to the Golden Olden Command-Line PreProcessing Interface and attempt to feed it to it somehow. We would start using Double Quotes, for instance, such as: `"libapr-1.dll"`.

Comment: Thanks, I think my question has not been clear enough, libapr-1.dll is within the message received from the system. And it's a dll from Apache runtime. The error message has been displayed BEFORE I enter any subversion routine.

Comment: Then please edit your question and insert the real Error Message in it. As it is written right now, it does not seem to be related in any way to the _Apache_ Web-Server at all. People get the impression that it is all related to the `subversion` Static Software Application. Also, four to five lines of question body are really insufficient for people to guess what it is all about.

Comment: I try to better explain the problem.
On Delphi XE5, on an old application, already on a SVN repository, after some code modifications, I had to commit them on svn.
Going to Project Manager, I right click on the application name. The context menu show "Add to version Control" , and I get an error message:"the filename, directory name, or volume label is incorrect: libapr-1.dll". Investigations on names and paths carried no solutions. My repository is located on external drive.

Comment: It is _still_ not clear. At least the "_The error message has been displayed BEFORE I enter any subversion routine_" sentence is still confusing. Again, four and a half lines of question body that are displayed on our displays are not helping much the readers. Please edit your question, insert some screen-shots and help the readers better understand your issue. For the moment, your latest description is the same as the first one to our eyes.

Comment: Dear Dobrescu,I am sorry you are not able to understand my problem. I have no more words to explain it and I presume that someone with good experience of Delphi and integrated SVN may understand it. This based both on my age and on my engineering experience. If the problem is my english, then I may better understand you as it's not mother language.I, personally, don't think the error comes from SVN system but from windows, anyhow may be Stackoverflow it's not the right place to ask. For the technology area and for too much difficulties to be understood. Have a nice evening.

Comment: What can we say, @Manlio? We have just tried to help. Screen-shots are always helping the readers better understand the Issues. And yours is not a trivial one. At a certain point, you were saying that "_it is a D.L.L. from the Apache runtime_". From your question description, nobody can get that it is related to the _Apache_ world in any way. Anyway, we have just given you some kind of suggestions. Good luck in your quest!

Comment: Dear Dobrescu, let me try to help the other way around: Run a Delphi code. whatever is and go step by step along my second description of the problem (forget Apache etc) and everything will appear clear. Thanks